# onProviderEnabled not working?

Tags: android, geolocation

For switching between GPS & Network location provider I just tried in a way like this, to identify when a provider is disabled switch to another, but my `onProviderEnabled()` is not getting invoked

```
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
  Toast.makeText(TrackerService.this, "Disabled : " + provider, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
  Toast.makeText(TrackerService.this, "Enabled : " + provider, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

Comment: did you written code like below or not ?

Comment: Use code as in below answer it will definitely work.

Comment: @YugandharBabu Please wait for a while, will let you know the update.

Comment: @YugandharBabu App running fine, but not switching to GPS provider when i switch ON GPS

Answer (score 3):

Define a location listener like the following:

```
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            }
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
        };
```

Then :

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
  lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
  lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, let me try this and will let you know the result.

Comment: jainal why you removed lm.removeUpdates(this);
lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork); from you answer, Something wrong in that.. i was about to try my app with that code..

Comment: if you want then you can remove your listener from inside the onLocationChanged.To make it more clear to you I removed that code.

Comment: app running fine, but not switching to GPS provider when i switch ON GPS, i think you done something similar before and sure can help me, this is more detail of my problem http://stackoverflow.com/q/8655928/681808 please see and suggest where i went wrong..

Comment: what do you mean by gps switching?when do you want to switch?switch from network to gps?

Comment: Switching i mean is, my app will be taking the location using network provider, and when user switch ON GPS the app should start using the GPS to get the location. I prefer GPS(accuracy factor) but if GPS not avail, still i should get Network provider(GSM) location..

Comment: ok...then i think you should a service for gps checking as there is not any listener or broadcast intent for gps on/off detection.It will always check for gps.If it is available then do your work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6310/discussion-between-lenin-and-jainal)

Comment: I just stumbled upon the same problem (`onProviderEnabled` not being fired).  

The reason was the same as in the question (so I assume, because the relevant code is missing):  
I wanted to switch the provider to `network` so I called `lm.removeUpdates(this)` in `onProviderDisabled` and then requested updates for `network`.  
Which caused all updates for `gps`, including `onProviderEnabled`, never to be triggered anymore.
The solution is what jainal wrote: Requesting updates for both providers in parallel.